# How to update an existing activity stream entry in IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am trying to update an existing activity stream entry e.g. the title of the entry.

Here I found the code for the creation of the new entry:
[Link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=POSTing_new_events_ic45&content=apicontent&sa=true)

But I could not find any reference how do I update an existing entry?

Additional information:

- I use IBM Connections 4.5 and the IBM SBT
- I create the entries with a system user to other users with the flag
  'actionable'

Here my questions:

- Which URL?
- Which Method (PUT?)?
- Which Json?

And another question about the actionable flag:

- How can I change the actionable flag for an entry of another user? The description for my own entries is described on slide 37 here: [Link](http://www.slideshare.net/soccnx/mikkel-heisterberg-an-introduction-to-working-with-the-activity-stream)

Thank you so much !
Markus

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I fully understand the issue now. As suggested this is not supported, but there is a way you can achieve the same result.

First of all why isn't it supported . . .

- Events are a point in time (and they were accurate at that point in time)
- A new event on the same object supersedes it (as it's now the most interesting) but
  doesn't invalidate it (it can still be seen in history)
- The Actionable view does not show a rolled up view, instead it shows all events that are marked actionable (and there may be multiple actions related to any given Object)

What you can do . . .

- If you want to replace an entry in the Actionable view, you can remove the event from the actionable view (it is just removed from that view and could still be seen in event history)
- You can then add another event to the actionable view (which as the latest event will also supersede events in other rolled up views)

Removing the actionable flag is here ->http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Support_for_Saved_and_Actionable_events&content=pdcontent

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is my problem. I found the solution to change the actionable flag for my own entries. But I create the entries with a system accout for other users. How can I change the actionable flag with the system user for the entries of other users?

Answer (score 1):

an activity stream object is treated an an immutable object in IBM Connections. 
you can Create Delete and Read.

You can use a rollup-id in IBM Connections.

> In order to address the scenario where a user posts a file and 200 people 'like' it, filling up their Activity Stream, rollup needs to be performed. This means:
>   Only the latest event on any given object is shown
>   The 2 most recent comments are returned.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Support_for_Rollup&content=apicontent

Comment: I asked colleagues to validate the first part, I recommend the second approach

Comment: Ok. I had tried it with rollup but the 'Actionable events views' does not support rollup and my entries are at first in this view. When I create a new entry to replace the information both entries are in the 'Actionable view' and not only the new one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rollup should work in any view.  You may want to create a new rollup id.

Comment: my colleague added more detail in his answer

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend the last answer, delete is not directly supported in the Activity Stream in IBM Connections, though a means of propagating delete based on deletion of an Object was introduced in IBM Connections 4.5.

However it does seem like submitting a new event with an appropriate rollup id is what you're looking for. That way users will see the latest, but the history remains and can be seen if desired.